Sufficient condition for uniform boundedness of the Hessian matrix of a real convex function
For context, I have an optimization problem
$$
\mathrm{min}_x f(x) 
$$
subject to a set of convex constraints, with $f: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ 
$f$ is convex but unpractical to manipulate and I wand to find a quadratic majorizer, i.e. a function
$$
g(x, y)=f(y)+(x-y)^\top b+\frac12 (x-y)^\top A(x-y)
$$
such that $g(x, y) \geq f(x) \;\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$
From Block Relaxation Methods in Statistics by Jan de Leeuw I have that:

uniform boundedness of the second derivatives [of $f$] is sufficient for quadratic majorizers to exist

What I have currently is this: with $H(x)$ the Hessian matrix of $f$ and $\Vert\cdot\Vert_2$ the spectral norm
$$
\left\Vert H(x)\right\Vert_2 = \lambda_{\max}\left(H(x)\right) < C \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$
With $C\in\mathbb{R}$
I have no background in functional analysis and I have trouble piecing together the information I found. From what I understand, this is enough to show uniform boundedness as it is the definition (in this case the vector norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the Euclidean norm).
My question is the following: does an upper bound on the spectral norm of the Hessian is a sufficient condition to have uniform boundedness? And if not, what would a sufficient condition be?


this is not functional analysis, just (real) analysis, 2) this is not always possible ( $f(x) = x^3$).

